# how to write a wrapper ruby class for encapsulating request/response to a 3rd party api client?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm pretty sure there are many similar questions, but I wanted to know if there is any good tutorial anyone has come across to write a ruby class for encapsulating request/response, error handling..., when making calls to 3rd party apis.

Comment: Search for "Service Pattern on ruby". It's how what you're trying to accomplish is generally called.

Comment: Asking for external tutorials is not really allowed here, it would be better if you showed your attempt or an example of your current request/response process

Answer (score 1):

you can have look at service design pattern on https://www.sitepoint.com/7-design-patterns-to-refactor-mvc-components-in-rails/